# Managing Memory in CoreGraphics / CoreText with Return Values

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have a simple method which takes in a `CTFramesetterRef` object and builds a `CTTextFrameRef` from that as follows:

```
- (CTFrameRef) createFrameRefWithFramesetterRef:(CTFramesetterRef)framesetterRef
{
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetterRef, CFRangeMake(0, 0), self.mutablePathRef, NULL);
    return frameRef;
}
```

Then in another method I make a call to the above method:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
     CTFramesetterRef framesetterRef = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFMutableAttributedStringRef)self.text);
     CTFrameRef newFrameRef = [self createFrameRefWithFramesetterRef:framesetterRef];
     //do some stuff
     CTRelease(newFrameRef);
     CTRelease(framesetterRef);
}
```

I just wanted to verify that I managed memory properly here as I am new to working with `CoreGraphics`. When `CTFramesetterCreateFrame` is called, retain is automatically called on `frameRef`. I don't have to worry about releasing `frameRef` when it's returned since it's stored in `newFrameRef` and the retain count stays the same. All I have to worry about is releasing `newFrameRef` (`CTRelease(newFrameRef)`). Is this correct?

UPDATE: I'm actually still getting a memory leak from this, one at the line with the return and one where I'm releasing "newFrameRef"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C-interface API's take their cues from the old Foundarion Kit naming guide, which has two distinct (and helpful) naming conventions called the [Get Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1) and the [Create Rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029).  For brevity's sake:  any C-function that has the word `create` in it returns a reference that you must manage manually.  So to answer your question, yes, you do need to release that `CTFramesetterRef`, because you've got a leak on your hands now.

Comment: Forgetting to release the CTFramesetterRef was just an oversight on my part, I changed that. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem.  The c-part of objective c is poorly documented anyhow.